# Adding html table row with jquery can not set as marked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a HTML file with a table. This table has about 7 entries (rows with data) by default. When the user clicks on one of these row the background color changes and it becomes marked, I did it with the jquery toggle function.
I also have a button which adds further rows in this table, also with jquery. My problem: When I (user) add some rows with that button and click on those new added rows the background color doesn't change but the background color of  default rows change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("activeRow");

    });
    $(document).on('click', '#addButton', function(){
    $(".myTable tbody").append(" <tr class=&quot;row&quot;> <td>New</td> <td>This</td> <td>is</td> <td>great</td> </tr>");
});


});
</script>
<style>
.activeRow{

    background-color:#B0BED9;
}
.myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    clear:both;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;



}
.myTable tbody, .myTable thead{

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.myTable tbody{

    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;

}

.myTable th, td{

    width: 450px;
}
</style
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr id="headRow">
    <th>alo</th>
    <th>salam</th>
    <th>kissa</th>
    <th>chissa</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="bodyRows">

            <tr class="row" >
            <td>Microsoft</td>
            <td>Saber</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
          <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
                  <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="row">
            <td>Huawei</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Google</td>
            <td>50.2</td>
            <td>40.63</td>
            <td>45.23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>25.4</td>
            <td>30.2</td>
            <td>33.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>IBM</td>
            <td>20.4</td>
            <td>15.6</td>
            <td>22.3</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>


 <button id="addButton" class="tableButton">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the row click events with .on method as well.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).on("click", ".myTable .row", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("activeRow");
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#addButton', function() {
        $(".myTable tbody").append(" <tr class='row'> <td>New</td> <td>This</td> <td>is</td> <td>great</td> </tr>");
      });


    });
```

```css
.activeRow {
  background-color: #B0BED9;
}
.myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.myTable tbody,
.myTable thead {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.myTable tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.myTable th,
td {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="headRow">

      <th>alo</th>
      <th>salam</th>
      <th>kissa</th>
      <th>chissa</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="bodyRows">

    <tr class="row">
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Saber</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Huawei</td>
      <td>20.3</td>
      <td>30.5</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Google</td>
      <td>50.2</td>
      <td>40.63</td>
      <td>45.23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>25.4</td>
      <td>30.2</td>
      <td>33.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>IBM</td>
      <td>20.4</td>
      <td>15.6</td>
      <td>22.3</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<button id="addButton" class="tableButton">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Okay thank you for response. What's the correct syntax to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the toggleClass behaviour to the existing rows, not the newly created ones. You need to add the event when you create new rows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".row").on('click', function (ev) {
    $(this).toggleClass("activeRow");
  });
  $('#addButton').on('click', function (ev) {
    $(".myTable tbody").append(' <tr class="row"> <td>New</td> <td>This</td> <td>is</td> <td>great</td> </tr>');
    $(".row").off('click').on('click', function (ev) { // off, to avoid overloading listeners on click event
      $(this).toggleClass("activeRow");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, what is "ev" you wrote in the function brackets?

Comment: You're not using it in this case. It's the event object, which comes to every function defined as an event callback. You can give it any name and then use it as a reference to inspect the event properties (type, target, currentTarget...)

Comment: I can't upvote because I got less than 15 reputations, sorry buddy but I marked it as working.